# Trouble installing Ubuntu on a virtual machine - low graphics mode

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 through VirtualBox. I get through the install process, but after I hit <kbd>restart now</kbd> when it restarts it says

> Ubuntu is running in Low Graphics mode. Your screen, graphics card, and input devices could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure them yourself.

The only valid option afterwards is to run in low-graphics mode for a session. It then takes me to a console, which is hardly what I wanted. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't hurt to try to install the X11 guest utilities for VirtualBox, in case they weren't installed automatically:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
```

If they're already loaded, you'll just get a message like "virtualbox-guest-x11 is already the latest version."

For good measure, reboot the VM after installing if you don't notice any immediate improvement.

Answer (score 0):

when starting ubuntu make sure the window of virtualbox is full screen. if it can achieve at least 800x600 xorg should start with vesa drivers.
if it doesnt start the problem is somewhere else
make sure you have internet connection into virtualbox when installing it.
As far as I know ubuntu installs guest additions automatically (I had to remove them manualy)

Comment: How do I verify that I have internet connection into virtualbox?

Comment: when instaling ubuntu instaler should have pointed it out